# UIActivityViewController error after migration to Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiactivityviewcontroller

The `ShareButton` function worked in Xcode 6, but it has an error after upgrading to `Xcode 7` in the line:

> avc.completionWithItemsHandler = {

My code:

```
 @IBAction func ShareButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let things = ["Thank you"]

    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:things, applicationActivities:nil)

    avc.setValue("Salon Job HK", forKey: "subject")

    avc.completionWithItemsHandler = {

        (s: String!, ok: Bool, items: [AnyObject]!, err:NSError!) -> Void in

    }

    self.presentViewController(avc, animated:true, completion:nil)

    if let pop = avc.popoverPresentationController {

        let v = sender as! UIView // sender would be the button view tapped, but could be any view

        pop.sourceView = v

        pop.sourceRect = v.bounds

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just check Swift 2.0 UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler's declaration:

> typealias UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler =
>   (String?, Bool, [AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> Void

try like this:

```
avc.completionWithItemsHandler = {

    (s: String?, ok: Bool, items: [AnyObject]?, err:NSError?) -> Void in

}
```

or simply:

```
avc.completionWithItemsHandler = {
    (s, ok, items, err) in

}
```

---

**Swift 3**

```
@IBAction func shareButton(sender: Any) {  
    let things = ["Thank you"]
    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: things, applicationActivities: nil)
    avc.setValue("Salon Job HK", forKey: "subject")
    avc.completionWithItemsHandler = {
        (activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError) in
        // code
    }
    present(avc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This changed again slightly for **Swift 3.0**:

```
UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler = (UIActivityType?, Bool, [Any]?, Error?) -> Void
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you can also set it to nil since you don't seem to be doing anything when the completion is called

```
avc.completionWithItemsHandler = nil
```